# SharePoint 2013 - Implications of stopping a Continuous crawl

Tags: 2013

I have a continuous crawl running in our Production environment.

I would like to switch this to a repeating incremental and a daily full crawl.

When I attempt to 'Enable Incremental Crawls' within the content source I get a pop-up message saying...
'Disabling continuous crawl may take a few minutes. Once disabled, we may initiate a clean-up incremental crawl.  You can stop or pause that crawl once disable crawl is complete.  Are you sure you want to disable continuous crawl?'

If I stop this crawl, will I impact the production site at all? Should I be switching crawls during off hours?

Comment: What is the main reason why you do not want to use Continuous crawl? Running an Incremental crawl every five minutes will probably not give you fresher data (if your environment is not very small)

Comment: I have two users that are not being pulled through in active directory. These users were taken out of the normal user group for testing purposes in active directory.  The users have since been put back into the correct user group.   In the crawl history I see that crawl types of 'C' and 'I' exist over the past week but no 'F'.  Based on the crawl history it doesn't seem that a full crawl has occurred. Just trouble shooting, but I am hoping a full crawl may pull these users back in.

Comment: I created another post better detailing my AD/People Search problem, if you are interested...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85044/sharepoint-2013-people-search-not-showing-all-ad-users

Comment: Ok, that was not really clear from your post where you talk about five minute schedule for incremental crawl (which is a bad idea because it is not possible to run multiple incremental crawls simultaneously, as opposed to using continuous crawl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Continuous Crawls should catch it all (assuming that they are SharePoint sites). There really is no reason to stop a Continuous Crawl unless you are doing maintenance, resetting the index, changing the current content sources, or deleting the UPS entirely. You can run any other kind of crawl on top of the continuous crawl while it's still running, it will not affect it.

Continuous Crawls are, in fact, constantly running, and stopping them to start another crawl, is analogous to stopping a car to switch lanes. They were built for the purpose of faster, fresher searches, without making any affect on other crawls. In previous versions crawls could not overlap, but you can overlap another type of crawl over a continuous crawl.