# SharePoint 2013 - People Search not showing all AD users

Tags: 2013, active-directory, people-search

I have a People Search set up on my SharePoint site.

The User Profile Sync service is set up to 'Use SharePoint Profile Synchronization'.

About a week ago, all users were coming into SharePoint and the People Search web part beautifully.  Then I had to test a group policy in Active Directory and I pulled two users out of the 'Normal User' group and put them in a test AD group (yes, I needed real users to test). They no longer appeared in the People Search, which I expected. I finished my test and put the two users back into the proper group within Active Directory.  Now I cannot get these users to come back into my People Search within SharePoint.

So far this is what I know - 
1. When I go into the CA - User Profile Sync Service Application - Edit Synchronization Connection and 'Populate Containers' the users I am looking for are part of the correct User Group and are selected.
2. Under the same User Profile Sync Service Application I can go to 'Manage User Profiles' and search for the users and they both come up as having Active Profiles.
3. The Search Service Application is set up to run a Continuous Crawl.
4. Changes to existing users are coming through the People Search webpart fine.  For example, yesterday a telephone number changed.  The change was made in Active Directory the new number came through into the People Search.

What else can I do to trouble shoot this?

Comment: Can you try doing a full user profile import and a full search crawl?

Comment: The Search Service is set to run a continuous crawl.  Can I just kick off a full crawl anytime with this running continuously?  (I have another post regarding this question specifically if you are able to help) http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85040/sharepoint-2013-implications-of-stopping-a-continuous-crawl?lq=1

Comment: I haven't gotten my hands on 2013 yet, I would assume in Central administration you can do manual full crawls then enable continuous crawling again.

Comment: As Pirate Eric stated, A Full User Profile import or a full search crawl should be kicked off manually. Keep your scheduled incremental crawl as is.

Comment: You can run a Full Crawl on top of the Continuous Crawl simultaneously.

Comment: Also look in the crawl logs and see if the profile is getting crawled. There should be an entry for every user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using this resource to help trouble shoot this issue...
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681014.aspx

We discovered that when looking at the user profiles, the Profile Sync uses the AD name to create users instead of the Netbios name.  To fix this we --

1. Used this resource to enable the Netbios Domain name
   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18060.sharepoint-20xx-what-if-the-domain-netbios-name-is-different-than-the-fqdn-of-the-domain-with-user-profile.aspx
2. Deleted the User Profile Sync and recreated the connection (This deleted all users and then re-added them - but didn't wipe out their sites).

Problem solved, all users now appear in the people search/staff directory.